# How to use OpenCV to crop circular image?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way in openCV that would allow me to crop image between two circles, in a way that ignores everything in the smaller inner circle and everything outside of the larger circle. Like a donut shape.

Comment: Post an example image. Are the two circles depicted in the image or do you  just know the common center and the the two radii or diameters?

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input and get its dimensions
- Define the radii of the two circles and the center coordinates
- Create a white filled circle mask on a black background for each radius
- Subtract the smaller radius mask from the larger radius mask
- Put the resulting mask image into the alpha channel of the input
- save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]
hh2 = hh // 2
ww2 = ww // 2

# define circles
radius1 = 25
radius2 = 75
xc = hh // 2
yc = ww // 2

# draw filled circles in white on black background as masks
mask1 = np.zeros_like(img)
mask1 = cv2.circle(mask1, (xc,yc), radius1, (255,255,255), -1)
mask2 = np.zeros_like(img)
mask2 = cv2.circle(mask2, (xc,yc), radius2, (255,255,255), -1)

# subtract masks and make into single channel
mask = cv2.subtract(mask2, mask1)

# put mask into alpha channel of input
result = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:, :, 3] = mask[:,:,0]

# save results
cv2.imwrite('lena_mask1.png', mask1)
cv2.imwrite('lena_mask2.png', mask2)
cv2.imwrite('lena_masks.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('lena_circle_masks.png', result)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('mask1', mask1)
cv2.imshow('mask2', mask2)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('masked image', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Smaller radius mask:

[image]

Larger radius mask:

[image]

Difference mask:

[image]

Resulting image:

[image]

Comment: The image size seems to stay the same, is there any way to reduce the size to the crop?

Comment: `@Olaf` It was not intended as a crop to the size of the donut shape. It was simply a way to make the output transparent outside the donut, but keep the output the same as the input.  What exactly do you want for the output?

Comment: I see, understood, what I was wondering about is how do you get the image to be the size of just the crop?

Comment: I do not understand, there is no crop in my command. If you need to crop the result, you should crop the alpha channel to the bounds of the donut by getting the bounding box of the external contour, then using Numpy slicing to crop the both the image.  Is that what you want to do or is it something else. If the latter, please explain in more detail or show and example.

Comment: The bounding box crop was exactly what I was looking for. I have it working now by doing: result[y0:y1,x0:x1]

Answer (score 0):

You should use masks. Create an empty image of the same size, draw the larger circle with value '1', then the smaller with value '0', you'll get a "donut", then use that donut as a mask to copy the part of your image you're interested in.

This might help as a tutorial:
https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-opencv-numpy-alpha-blend-mask/

Comment: After applying the method mentioned in that tutorial, is it possible to remove alpha channel? I need a 2D image but I am getting a 3D one