# how to cut picture with circle mask that has alpha color?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, mask

i have a problem where i need to go from this input:

First Input `src1 = input2.png` :

[image]

applying this `src2 = input2.png` as a mask:

[image]

to get this output:

[image]

I have tried to, but i didnt know how specifiy that the outer color is alpha color (completely transparent) i either endup with black or white.

```
src1 = cv2imread('input1.png')
src2 = cv2.imread('input2.png')
```

##### both same size

```
print(src2.dtype)
# uint8

dst = cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2)

cv2.imwrite('res.jpg', dst)
```

Comment: please post the code you tried, to have something to work on

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia this is the tutorial i followed https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-opencv-numpy-alpha-blend-mask/

Comment: Please, post the code on the question, not a link to a page that one day might be taken down

Comment: except from this, looks like that this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61516526/how-to-use-opencv-to-crop-circular-image is what you are looking for

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes i saw that question days ago but outer space of the circle is not alpha color.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using openCV to overlay transparent image onto another image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz srry bro i missed this comment but it doesnt answer the question fmw42 posted the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

Just read the second image unchanged. Then copy the alpha channel from the second to the first image.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read images
img1 = cv2.imread('picture1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('picture2.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# copy alpha from second image to first image
result = img1.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:,:,3] = img2[:,:,3]

# save results
cv2.imwrite('picture1_circled.png', result)
```

Result:

[image]