# cv2.imshow does not seem to hide transparent pixels

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to obtain a circle ROI based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61551618/15936471) (so I can try and find the average RGB color within the circle). I created a white-filled circle mask at the center of the image and put the mask into the alpha channel of the image. `cv2.imshow()`, however, seems to ignore the alpha channel. How can I get cv2.imshow() to show the circle?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("Assets/Setup.jpg")
height, width = img.shape[:2]
mask = cv2.circle(np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8), (width // 2, height // 2), width // 2, 255, -1)
result = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:, :, 3] = mask
cv2.imshow("Frame", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: opencv imshow doesnt handle alpha channel at all. Use a different gui library if you need such a feature

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684791/2836621

Comment: Just save the image to disk and you will then see it if you open the file.